# Image search for languages with a weak internet presence

Tags: mongolian, research-techniques

I'm setting up flash cards with the word in the L2, and an image of the object, as suggested in "Fluent Forever". The book suggests [doing the search in the L2](https://fluent-forever.com/chapter4/):

> If you’re actually learning a word like chien, rather than a more
>   complex sentence, I strongly suggest you search in French. You’ll
>   almost always find some differences between your expectations and what
>   you actually see. These differences make the image search process a
>   lot more interesting, and as a result, the word becomes a lot more
>   interesting. In the case of chien (dog), the differences are pretty
>   subtle, but they’re there. Chiens are cuter, are more often puppies or
>   silly looking lap-dogs, and don’t tend to be photographed with their
>   owners. Sure you could use chien to refer to Lassie, but generally,
>   chiens are little foofy French dogs.

However, when I search for words, sometimes I get hits of a word, often unrelated, spelt the same way in another language. For example, searching for "гол", which is river in Mongolian, gets a lot of hits in Russian and Ukrainian for their translation of the sporting term "goal".

How can I do an image search for a given word for languages with a weak internet presence?

I've tried using a country-specific search engine site ([google.mn](https://www.google.mn/search?q=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB&biw=1311&bih=742&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia7eHH75rOAhXBl5QKHXkFBMIQ_AUIBigB) rather than [google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB&biw=1311&bih=778&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYvdrf75rOAhVFm5QKHQUODyEQ_AUIBygC)), and it's helped somewhat, but isn't foolproof.

The Fluent Forever website [suggests](https://fluent-forever.com/chapter4/) using English as a fallback, but I want to know if there's any hacks that can help further.

Comment: @bytebuster updated question in response.

Comment: I absolutely agree your motivation, it is very clear. Still I believe that for the purpose of *flash cards*, this may be a bit of over-perfection. Keep in mind that flash-cards is a tool for associative memory, *which memory is inaccurate by its nature*. Personally. I would totally tolerate some minor inaccuracies, like having a mature dog on the picture instead of *chien*. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish that:

1. [Bing](http://bing.com) has `language:` search filter. This screenshot is pretty much self-evident:

   [image: Bing search for гол]
2. [Google](http://google.com): After the search, click "Search tools" and then choose to filter your language.
   Caveat: Only your browser's primary language can be chosen, shame on Google.
3. Google's [Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search) has a drop-down for language selection.
   Caveat: Mongolian isn't there, shame on Google.
4. Google's Search also accepts `lr` parameter like this:
   `https://www.google.com/search?as_q=гол&lr=lang_be`
   But again, Mingolian isn't there, note I've chosen Bielorussian here.

---

## Further reading:

- [Advanced Query Language for Bing](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/bing_advanced_search.htm)

Answer (score 6):

For a few languages (sadly, not Mongolian), you can tell Google Image search to search results in your target language (note that English is always included):

Click on the Settings gear icon in the top right corner, then Languages.  From that page, click 'Edit' under **Currently showing search results in:**.  You'll see a list of languages you can choose.

Answer (score 3):

If your language is associated with a particular country, try adding a search restriction for images only from that specific country.

[google.mn гол](https://www.google.mn/search?q=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB&biw=1311&bih=742&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOuK-b8ZrOAhUGv5QKHUKDD98Q_AUIBigB) versus [google.mn гол site:.mn](https://www.google.mn/search?biw=1311&bih=742&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%20site%3A.mn&oq=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%20site%3A.mn&gs_l=img.3...1041.3739.0.3953.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0.ZQEp4F0EmkU)